# Is there a GSL implementation I can use with GCC 4.9.x?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

Microsoft's (Core) Guidelines Support Library implementation is said to support GCC 5.1 - but does not specify support for other versions. Higher versions seem to be ok (anyway, 5.3.1 on my Debian Stretch) - but building the tests with GCC 4.9.3 fails.

- Has anybody else implemented the GSL?
- Can I use MS GSL anyway, somehow?
- If not, can I use some safe subset of it? (Probably not, I know)
- If not, isn't it a problem that only people with newer compilers can have a guidelines support libraries? Even though their older compilers support C++11 or even C++14?

Comment: Problem for who? You could open a feature request at MS if you think it's on them?

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Problem for the world. Or, you know what, problem for Prof. Stroustrup and Herb Sutter who are promoting the Core Guidelines. At any rate, I will make a request. Anyway, edited the question.

Comment: MS/GSL requires C++14, it is not intended for C++11. gcc before gcc5 does not fully support C++14 ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp14)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is one I know of: [gsl-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite).

It worked fine for me so far. But I changed my compiler to a newer version and did not need it anymore.

You can also use (a rather small) subset of Microsofts implementation. If you do not need the `span`-classes. These are `gsl_assert.h` (`Expects`, `Ensures`) and `gsl_utils.h` (`narrow`, `final_act`, ...). I think I might have adjusted just some `constexpr` related things.

Comment: Actually I personally do want the span classes, but others might not need it, so that's useful too. Will try gsl-lite. Is there something missing from it?

Comment: No strided views! But 1-d spans are in it. I completely understand you.